# knockout JS unable to access the elements of observableArray

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, oracle-jet

I have created knockout observable array and added element as below,

```
define(['ojs/ojcore', 'knockout', 'jquery', 'ojs/ojtable', 'ojs/ojarraytabledatasource', 'ojs/ojrouter'],
 function(oj, ko, $) {

    function CustomerViewModel() {
      var self = this;
      self.data = ko.observableArray([]);

      var getDataUrl = <rest-api-url>
      var fetchDataPayLoad = JSON.stringify(<json_data>);

      self.fetchData = function(fetchDataPayLoad, fetchDataCallBack) {
             $.ajax({
               url: getDataUrl,
               data: fetchDataPayLoad,
               type: 'POST',
               contentType: 'application/json',
               success: fetchDataCallBack,
               error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                 console.log('Error during fetch');
               }
             });
           };

      function fetchDataCallBack(fetchedData){
             fetchedData.hits.hits.forEach(function(e){
                 var value1 = e._id;
                 value2 = e._value;
                 value3 = e.name;
                 value4 = e.testdata;
                 self.data.push({
                   prop1: value1,
                   prop2: value2,
                   prop3: value3,
                   prop4: value4
                 });
               });
             });
           };
           var fetchDataRun = this.fetchData(fetchDataPayLoad, fetchDataCallBack);
           console.log(self.data());
}
    return new CustomerViewModel();
}
);
```

When am trying to check the lenght of the observableArray getting 0 always and when I print the same got data as below on console,

```
>[]
```

and when I expand,

```
>0: {prop1: "value11", prop2: "value12", prop3: "value13", prop4: "value14"}
>1: {prop1: "value21", prop2: "value22", prop3: "value23", prop4: "value24"}
```

Not sure what am doing wrong/missing here, May I know how to access the observableArray element?

Comment: Im not familiar with KO, but why you are calling data when its not a function? console.log(self.data().length);

Comment: in what scope do you run this code? is it inside a function? i cant find any problems with this code, i made some checks and couldn't reproduce the error.
can you upload example in runkit website?

Comment: Because you are invoking data as a function from "self" object, it might cause some issues because data as a function has its own properties that it tries to access them with the "this" keyword, once you invoke data function through "self" object you are addressing the "self" object reference to the "this" keyword that is being used inside "data" function, please try to replace the print line with this: `console.log(self.ob.call(self.ob).length)` please tell me if it works for you.

Comment: @Lihai As you suggested I tried `console.log(self.data.call(self.data).length);` which also not working. I have updated the question with the entire viewModel.

Comment: Oh i see, of course its not working, the ajax request is asynchronous it means that the line `console.log(self.data());` is not blocked by the previous line: `var fetchDataRun = this.fetchData(fetchDataPayLoad, fetchDataCallBack);` and by the time you are outputting the array its empty because the asynchronous request did not resolve. what you need to do is creating a Promise object like so: `var promise = new Promise(....)` for the ajax request put the printing line inside `promise.then(function(){....});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the location of your `console.log`.

```
function fetchDataCallBack(fetchedData){
    fetchedData.hits.hits.forEach(function(e){
        var value1 = e._id;
        value2 = e._value;
        value3 = e.name;
        value4 = e.testdata;
        self.data.push({
            prop1: value1,
            prop2: value2,
            prop3: value3,
            prop4: value4
        });
    });
    console.log(self.data());
});
```

Your Ajax call is asynchronous, meaning that the callback function executes only after the call is complete. Currently you are using `console.log` while the Ajax call is still running in the background and hence it shows as empty. See [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rpQJAWha8ns) for a visual explanation.